# Maven Shade Plugin - add version of dependency jar in MANIFEST

Tags: maven, jar, maven-shade-plugin

I'm using the shade plugin to deploy a 'fat' jar of our application. One of the dependencies in our application utilizes

```
ClassName.class.getPackage().getImplementationVersion();
```

Which, from my understanding and experience thus far, takes the version found in \META-INF\MANIFEST.MF

Since I am using the shade plugin, all dependencies are exploded and brought up into the top level jar. This dependency has a version check and is now returning the version of MY application, not the version of the dependency. I found one hacky workaround to override my application version in MANIFEST.MF by using the POM changes below, but is there a better way to do this? I lose my application version in the MANIFEST file.

```
<transformers>
  <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
    <manifestEntries>
      <mainClass>path.to.main.class</mainClass>
      <Implementation-Version>OVERRIDEN_VERSION_HERE</Implementation-Version>
      <Specification-Version>OVERRIDEN_VERSION_HERE</Specification-Version>
    </manifestEntries>
  </transformer>
</transformers>
```

I tried overriding my application version by hardcoding the version of the dependency in my application's MANIFEST.MF file, which worked, but curious if there is a better way to do this